# Dynamic video streaming in Flash

Tags: flash, video, dynamic, streaming

Is there any way to do dynamic video streaming in Flash without using Flash Media Server (FMS) 3.5 as it's a very expensive software. I'd like to use some open-source software or any other way.

Answer (score 0):

There are some alternatives.

[Wowza](http://www.wowzamedia.com/) is a lot cheaper! They also have a [Amazon EC2](http://www.wowzamedia.com/ec2.html) package.

For free, [Red5](http://osflash.org/red5) is open source.